# play store app update does not show

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

One weird problem. After update of an app (version code and version name) in play store changes has been appeared (version code is different and whats new appears), but there is no button "update", just "uninstall" and "open" as nothing is changed...

Comment: Please give it some more time .... it takes upto 8 hrs at times for the updates to be completely pushed out

Comment: ... And if you are checking the Play Store using your app that you debug with, you might have the latest version installed.

Comment: It lasts 30 hours from upload. Play store console registered changes but without of button for update. Package is the same...

Comment: what was the solution for your problem?